# A more generalized expand.grid function?

Tags: r

expand.grid(a,b,c) produces all the combinations of the values in a,b, and c in a matrix - essentially filling the volume of a three-dimensional cube. What I want is a way of getting slices or lines out of that cube (or higher dimensional structure) centred on the cube.

So, given that a,b, c are all odd-length vectors (so they have a centre), and in this case let's say they are of length 5. My hypothetical slice.grid function:

```
slice.grid(a,b,c,dimension=1)
```

returns a matrix of the coordinates of points along the three central lines. Almost equivalent to:

```
rbind(expand.grid(a[3],b,c[3]),
      expand.grid(a,b[3],c[3]),
      expand.grid(a[3],b[3],c))
```

almost, because it has the centre point repeated three times. Furthermore:

```
slice.grid(a,b,c,dimension=2)
```

should return a matrix equivalent to:

```
rbind(expand.grid(a,b,c[3]), expand.grid(a,b[3],c), expand.grid(a[3],b,c))
```

which is the three intersecting axis-aligned planes (with repeated points in the matrix at the intersections).

And then:

```
slice.grid(a,b,c,dimension=3)
```

is the same as expand.grid(a,b,c).

This isn't so bad with three parameters, but ideally I'd like to do this with N parameters passed to the function expand.grid(a,b,c,d,e,f,dimension=4) - its unlikely I'd ever want dimension greater than 3 though.

It could be done by doing expand.grid and then extracting those points that are required, but I'm not sure how to build that criterion. And I always have the feeling that this function exists tucked in some package somewhere...

[Edit] Right, I think I have the criterion figured out now - its to do with how many times the central value appears in each row. If its less than or equal to your dimension+1...

But generating the full matrix gets big quickly. It'll do for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `a`, `b` and `c` each have length 3 (and if there are 4 variables then they each have length 4 and so on) try this.  It works by using 1:3 in place of each of `a`, `b` and `c` and then counting how many 3's are in each row.  If there are four variables then it uses 1:4 and counts how many 4's are in each row, etc.  It uses this for the index to select out the appropriate rows from `expand.grid(a, b, c)` :

```
slice.expand <- function(..., dimension = 1) {
    L <- lapply(list(...), seq_along)
        n <- length(L)
    ix <- rowSums(do.call(expand.grid, L) == n) >= (n-dimension)
    expand.grid(...)[ix, ]
}

# test
a <- b <- c <- LETTERS[1:3]
slice.expand(a, b, c, dimension = 1)
slice.expand(a, b, c, dimension = 2)
slice.expand(a, b, c, dimension = 3)
```

Comment: Yep, I've done something like this, but I'm more interested in the midpoints, so I've tested against the middle value of the sequence. Would be nice to do it without throwing away two lots of most of an expand.grid though :) Tick for you.